# How do I get Zend Framework 2 to allow empty input

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2, emptydatatext

I want to allow empty input in some of the fields on my form. My form class is in one file and its filter is in another. The filter looks like the following

```
class ReportFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name'       => 'field_1',
            'required'   => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'filters'    => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
        ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'field_2',
        'required'   => false,
        'allow_empty' => true,
        'filters'    => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
    ));
```

The problem is that even though required is set to false and allow_empty is set to true, when the form is submitted without anything in these fields the validation fails and they are tagged with the message "Value is required and can't be empty". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this notation?

```
...
'allowEmpty'=>true, //insetad of allow_empty
...
```

Edition notes: try to split the element declaration from the filter options, like in the example below:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;

class ReportFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name'       => 'field_1',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        ));        
    }
    public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->filter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory ();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'field_1',
                'required' => false,
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                )));
            $this->filter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->filter;
    }
    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception('It is not allowed to set the input filter');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did try 'allowEmpty' instead of 'allow_empty'. It did not change anything.

Comment: Check the new code I typed. That's how I got it working in my app.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html), `use validators "not_empty"`

```
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory;

$factory = new Factory();
$inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter(array(
    'password' => array(
        'name'       => 'password',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'not_empty',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'string_length',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 8
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));

$inputFilter->setData($_POST);
echo $inputFilter->isValid() ? "Valid form" : "Invalid form";
```

**BONUS**

Zend Framework 2 give a lot of tools for your forms.

This is a good exemple with `Fieldset` and `InputFilterProviderInterface`. If you use Doctrine you can also use "Hydrator" to bind the form automatically into your entity. And with this code no problem `required => false` is enought and allow empty string

```
class AddressFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        parent::__construct('attribute');
        // $em = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        // $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, 'MyProject\...\Entity\AddressEntity'))->setObject(new AddressEntity());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'attributes' => array(
                'autocomplete' => 'off'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Address'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'span3',
                'autocomplete' => 'off'
            )
        ));


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'district',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'District'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'postal_code',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Postal code'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'city',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'City'
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'name' => array(
                'required' => false,
            ),
            'address' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'district' => array(
                'required' => false,
            ),
            'postal_code' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'city' => array(
                'required' => true,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

then you create a Form which contain your fieldset

Very good sample in the official documentation, if you control Form Fieldset and Hydrator ( for your database ) you will win a lot of time. And of course in my exemple I specify if the input is required or not, you can add custom validator too.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Comment: I do not see how this provides a solution to my problem. While I am glad that you get it to work in a completely different situation, I really need a solution for this specific situation.

Comment: I edit my answer for your case. But have a look on Fieldset it's good practice for Form validation on client side.